# How to use predicate search with Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

We are using Linq-to-SQL with SQL Server as an ORM on our new project. I have never used Linq-to-SQL before, so my question can be a bit dumb. I want to have a method that will perform a search for entities  in DB by predicate, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> @where)
```

Could you give some advices where I can see some code samples or ideas how to implement this?

Comment: hm... don't see how can it help me to send requests to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Where (here, originalList is any enumerable, in particular it can be a table from your context):

```
var filteredList = originalList.Where(element => ShouldBeIncluded(element));
```

Edit:

or

```
var filteredList =
    from element in originalList
    where ShouldBeIncluded(element)
    select element;
```

And if ShouldBeIncluded is a `Func<T, bool>`, there's an eye-candy simplified syntax:

```
var filteredList = originalList.Where(ShouldBeIncluded);
```

Edit 2: also, note that the complete syntax is:

```
var filteredList = originalList.Where<TTypeOfElement>(element => ShouldBeIncluded(element));
```

But the generic argument can be omitted since the compiler will deduce it from the type of originalList (supposing it is an `IEnumerable<TTypeOfelement>`).